# Remote control for distribution upgrade

Tags: unity, 13.10, upgrade, 14.04, remote-access

I've launched distribution upgrade (from 13.10 to 14.04) in Unity. Upgrade is running, but at the moment I don't have physical access to that machine (SSH is active)

1. How can I verify in shell status of running upgrade launched in Unity?
2. Can I complete the running upgrade via bash (aka answer to config file merge dialogs which pops up during upgrade) ?